# Failed to Instantiate Module Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

i am beginner in angularjs.i write a small code .i have three files.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="docsTransclusionDirective">
<head>
    <title>Hello Dude</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>
<body >
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   Check out the contents, {{name}} !
</div>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('docsTransclusionDirective', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Tobias';
    })
    .directive('myDialog', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html'
      };
    });
```

my-dialog.html

```
<div class="alert" ng-transclude>
  </div>
```

its giving me error :

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'docsTransclusionDirective' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/nomod?p0=docsTransclusionDirective
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:78:12
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1531:17
    at ensure (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1456:38)
    at module (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1529:14)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:3632:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:304:11)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:3626:5)
    at createInjector (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:3566:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1301:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=docsTransclusionDi…googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.js%3A1301%3A20) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:3660
forEach angular.js:304
loadModules angular.js:3626
createInjector angular.js:3566
doBootstrap angular.js:1301
bootstrap angular.js:1316
angularInit angular.js:1265
(anonymous function) angular.js:20869
trigger angular.js:2355
(anonymous function) angular.js:2626
forEach angular.js:311
eventHandler
```

can any one please tell why i am facing this error how to get rid from this ??

Comment: invalid html, close your script tag for script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine...

http://jsbin.com/rudacaro/2/edit?html,output

Make sure `script.js` is being loaded properly.

`<script>` tags can't be self closing. Needs to be `<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta - No you shouldn't. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/69984/476786